# Calculate the difference between two list, and store the result in a third list. Python

Tags: python, list

How would I calculate the difference between two separate list and store them in a third list.

for example...

```
list_1 [('M', 4000.0), ('R', 5320.0)]
list_2 [('M', 4222.0), ('R', 5442.0)]
```

I tried the following

```
list_3 = []

list_3.append([list_1] - [list_2])

print(list_3)
```

but I'm met with, a TypeError

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

Comment: How do you define the "difference" of those lists?

Comment: Looks like you have a list of tuples.

Comment: @rici - difference between the number values. So for example the difference with list_1 is as we can see is 222.0.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman Thank you for the input, what do you recommend in resolving this, list(zip())?

Comment: Isn't it `('M', -222)`? Or did you really mean to drop the first element? And what if the first elements differ? Also, why do you see 222 and not -222? Is it because you meant *the absolute value* of the difference? Programming is, first and foremost, about precision. You can't solve a problem that you can't precisely define, and much less someone else.

Comment: @rici the first elements remain the same. I'm working through a codecademy code challenge and I'm not an experienced developer, so forgive me if my question is not pinpoint precise, and this may be the reason I also see 222 and not -222.

Comment: I understand that. I mention the importance of precision because I assume your goal is to learn how to become an experienced developer, which requires learning some skills not necessarily promoted by "code challenges". One of those skills is being able to precisely articulate a problem; often, you will find that a program almost writes itself once you succeed in grasping the actual problem. (Indeed, a programming language is just a tool for unambiguously writing down a problem solution.) Another important and often-ignored skill is debugging. Good luck with your learning.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like something better suited to a dictionary

```
dict_1 = {'M': 4000.0, 'R': 5320.0}
dict_2 = {'M': 4222.0, 'R': 5442.0}

dict_3 = {}
dict_3['M'] = dict_1['M'] - dict_2['M']
dict_3['R'] = dict_1['R'] - dict_2['R']
```

If you're set on using a list of tuples you could do something with

```
tuple(map(operator.add, tup1, tup2)
```

which allows you to add and subtract tuples. You would have to do something about the string values though

Comment: You need to create a `dict` for `dict_3` in the first place. And there's nothing inherently superior about `dict`s here; you're just replacing one lightweight analogue for objects (`tuple`s) with another less lightweight analogue for objects (`dict`s). The OP's original data as a `list` of `tuple`s doesn't make a lot of sense, but without knowing why it's arranged that way (e.g. are they matching on first element of each `tuple`, or positionally within the `list`? are duplicates possible?), there is no guarantee `dict`s will work.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Dictionaries allow you to match the keys without depending on the order of elements.

Comment: @ randomletters356 Thanks for the answer. but I'm working through a codecademy code challenge and its asking me to solve this with lists, and not dictionaries.

Comment: Could you link or post the question?

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's one possibility, which might or might not be what you want. It assumes that the tuples are in the same order in both lists and does not verify that the first elements of corresponding tuples are the same (which is possibly a bug in waiting). It produces the result of subtracting the numeric values in the second list from the numeric values in the first list, rather than the absolute value of the differences; in your example, both numbers are negative. (If you wanted the absolute value, use `abs(v1 - v2)`)

It uses zip to combine the two lists, and a list comprehension to put the computed results back together into a list.

```py
>>> def diff(list_1, list_2):
...     return [(first, v1 - v2) for ((first, v1), (_, v2)) in zip(list_1, list_2)]
... 
>>> 
>>> list_1 = [('M', 4000.0), ('R', 5320.0)]
>>> list_2 = [('M', 4222.0), ('R', 5442.0)]
>>> diff(list_1, list_2)
[('M', -222.0), ('R', -122.0)]
```

Comprehensions are good when you need to do an element-by-element computation from one or more input lists. The comprehension just states how to create each output element from the inputs; the possibly-unfamiliar syntax in the `for` clause states how to decompose the inputs into individual pieces for use by the computation.

`zip` takes two or more lists and constructs an iterator of tuples; the tuples take one value from each list and the iterator continues until one of the lists is exhausted. So if `list1` is a list of `X`s and `list2` is a list of `Y`s, `zip(list1, list2)` produces an iterator over tuples of `(X, Y)`. In this case, `X` and `Y` are both tuples, with the same structure: a letter and a number. So `zip` creates tuples of the form `((letter, number), (letter, number))` and the `for` clause takes that apart using the pattern `((first, v1), (_, v2))`, which precisely matches the structure of the zipped tuples. (It must match or Python would complain.)

I use the variable name `_` to indicate that the value is ignored (that's a convention, not a rule, but later you'll find that it is a rule in some Python constructs). The letter from the second list is ignored because there's nothing in the problem description which indicates what to do with it.